# Android session management with node server

Tags: android, node.js

One of our site is using express-session management with node server. I am able to call all the URLs from Android however not able to maintain the sessions at Android end. Please advise.

Comment: please let me know i you got the answer.. email: suryabhai.raj@gmail.com.. i would be very thankful to you :)